# Swing : Setting JButton's background

Tags: java, swing, background-color, jbutton

I want to set the background color of JButton. For that I use 
   setBackground() method.

This method jsut sets the border color of the button and not the whole button of the specified color. Why so ? This is the only method to set background color of a button. Where am I making a mistake due to which it sets just the border of the button of specified color and not actual button ?

Code :

```
    account_btn.setAction(actionMap.get("AccountingClicked")); // NOI18N
    account_btn.setBackground(Utility.getBackgroundColor());
    account_btn.setFont(Utility.getButtonFont());
    account_btn.setForeground(Utility.getTextColor());
    org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap resourceMap = org.jdesktop.application.Application.getInstance(cashaccountingapp.CashAccountingApp.class).getContext().getResourceMap(MainPanel.class);
    account_btn.setText(resourceMap.getString("account_btn.text")); // NOI18N
    account_btn.setBorderPainted(false);
    account_btn.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    account_btn.setName("account_btn"); // NOI18N
    account_btn.setOpaque(true);
    add(account_btn);
```

Result :
[image]

Have tried setting setOpaque(true) also. But you can see the results of account_btn i.e. "Accounting". setOpaque seems to have no effects.

Any idea.

SOLUTION :

Setting L&F

```
    private void initLookandFeel() {
    try {
        System.out.println("DEFAULT Look & Feel = " + UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().toString());
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this.mainPanel);
        System.out.println("Look & Feel = " + UIManager.getLookAndFeel().toString());
    } catch(Exception e) { ..... }
    }
```

I call initLookandFeel() after initComponents() and also update my mainPanel. Also needed to update my dynamically added panel at initial stage then no need to set anything more.

Comment: What PLAF?  Where is your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: I am not sure if the edit to your question was an attempt to address comments by me.  If that is the case, you seem to have missed my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Red Buttons]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ColoredButtons {

    ColoredButtons() {
        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0,5,5));

        JButton one = new JButton("One");
        one.setBackground(Color.RED);
        JButton two = new JButton("Two");
        two.setBackground(Color.RED);

        gui.add(one);
        gui.add(two);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ColoredButtons();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

There is my SSCCE.  The buttons are red.  The PLAF is metal.

Which brings me back to:  Where is your SSCCE?  What PLAF are you using?

Comment: Andrew, am using NetBeans and have not set any PLAF. In searched in files but couldn't find any such. Am I missing location to search.

Comment: *"Am I missing location to search."*  How should I know, I don't use Netbeans.  What is the exact behavior of the posted code in your IDE?

Comment: @Tvd: In NetBeans, simply look at the GUI code it generates. In source view, search for LookAndFeel, and you'll likely find all the information that you need to allow Andrew to help you better. 1+ to Andrew for his (always) helpful suggestions, and congrats on breaking the 20K barrier.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"congrats on breaking the 20K barrier."*  I feel like I should have swept wings, or something.  ;)

Comment: Exactly. I found that wherever I go in the house a *boom* occurs, and the room shakes a little. I think that its due to me breaking the 20K barrier, but my wife says it's from the beans I had for dinner last night.

Comment: There is no "LookAndFeel", "setUI" in the code - main class and the Panel class.

Comment: So where is your SSCCE? Why do you need to be asked multiple times? Also, you can always use the UIManager class to print the current LAF.

Comment: Thanks everybody for helping me out. I figured out the soluiotn and have also added in the question itself. Wondering Default L&F is Windows and I set to Metal - Metal works perfectly well and Windows doesn't work.

Comment: BTW, can you help me know what do you mean by "Where is your SSCCE" ? I ead the link provided but couldn't get what are you expecting from me. I have never come across this earlier. Please help me know so can be helpful in future in required.

Comment: @Tvd: Many (most?) of Andrew's answers include exemplary [sscce](http://sscce.org/)s like this one. As you have found, not all L&F's support changing a button's background color.

Comment: @trashgod, yes only Metal helped me. I thought that wont do work so tried it last, but that only worked out. Anyways, what is this SSCCE that many are referring here. I have provided sufficient details, was trying a lot. Still ppl asking "Where is my SSCCE" ? what does that mean.

Comment: The code in this answer is an [sscce](http://sscce.org/). It is a "Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example," hence the acronym

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `Jbutton` background is controlled by the particular look-and-feel you are using.  To change the background you may need to modify the

```
setUI(ComponentUI newUI)
```

with your own one.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting border painted to false and opaque true

```
account_btn.setBorderPainted(false);
account_btn.setOpaque(true);
```